# Fail2ban does not start actionban even though the filter works

Tags: fail2ban

I'm trying to filter out malicious requests to our website on our AWS Instances through adding and removing IPs in the WAF IP sets. I'm trying to set up fail2ban to help with this.

These are the files -

#### jail.local

```
[my-jail]
enabled = true
filter = my-filter
action = my-action
  sendmail-whois[name=Fail2Ban Test, dest=my-name@my-org.de, sender=EC2-Fail2Ban@my-org.de, sendername="Fail2Ban"]
logpath = /var/log/apache2/frontend-app-my-org-com-access.log
maxretry = 4
findtime = 60
bantime = 300
journalmatch = _SYSTEMD_UNIT=httpd.service
```

#### my-action.conf

```
[Definition]

actionstart = touch /var/log/fail2ban_debug.log
actionstop = rm -f /var/log/fail2ban_debug.log

actionban = /opt/scripts/ban.sh Ban <ip>
actionunban = /opt/scripts/ban.sh Unban <ip>
```

---

Note: the `/opt/scripts/ban.sh` is executable and when tested manually via `/opt/scripts/ban.sh Ban 10.10.10.10` I get the expected result. All files are owned and managed by the `root` user. The fail2ban service is also started via the root user.

#### my-filter.conf

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> - - \[.*\] \".*.my-org.*\" \".*\" [4-5][0-9][0-9]
```

#### Regex check

When I manually check the filter against my logs - it works:

```
[root@ip-172-31-89-74 action.d]# fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/frontend-app-my-org-com-access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/my-filter.conf | grep matched
Lines: 2325 lines, 0 ignored, 2325 matched, 0 missed
```

#### logs

```
2023-10-16 15:03:08,737 fail2ban.server         [9162]: INFO    --------------------------------------------------
2023-10-16 15:03:08,737 fail2ban.server         [9162]: INFO    Starting Fail2ban v0.11.2
2023-10-16 15:03:08,737 fail2ban.server         [9162]: DEBUG   Creating PID file /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid
2023-10-16 15:03:08,738 fail2ban.observer       [9162]: INFO    Observer start...
2023-10-16 15:03:08,738 fail2ban.server         [9162]: DEBUG   Starting communication
2023-10-16 15:03:08,742 fail2ban.database       [9162]: INFO    Connected to fail2ban persistent database '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3'
2023-10-16 15:03:08,742 fail2ban.jail           [9162]: INFO    Creating new jail 'my-jail'
2023-10-16 15:03:08,748 fail2ban.jail           [9162]: INFO    Jail 'my-jail' uses systemd {}
2023-10-16 15:03:08,748 fail2ban.filter         [9162]: DEBUG   Setting usedns = warn for FilterSystemd(Jail('my-jail'))
2023-10-16 15:03:08,748 fail2ban.filter         [9162]: DEBUG   Created FilterSystemd(Jail('my-jail'))
2023-10-16 15:03:08,749 fail2ban.filtersystemd  [9162]: DEBUG   Created FilterSystemd
2023-10-16 15:03:08,749 fail2ban.jail           [9162]: INFO    Initiated 'systemd' backend
2023-10-16 15:03:08,749 fail2ban.filter         [9162]: DEBUG   Setting usedns = warn for FilterSystemd(Jail('my-jail'))
2023-10-16 15:03:08,749 fail2ban.server         [9162]: DEBUG     failregex: '^<HOST> - - \\[.*\\] \\".*.my-org.*\\" \\".*\\" [4-5][0-9][0-9]'
2023-10-16 15:03:08,750 fail2ban.filtersystemd  [9162]: INFO    [my-jail] Added journal match for: '_SYSTEMD_UNIT=httpd.service'
2023-10-16 15:03:08,750 fail2ban.filter         [9162]: INFO      maxRetry: 4
2023-10-16 15:03:08,750 fail2ban.filter         [9162]: INFO      encoding: UTF-8
2023-10-16 15:03:08,750 fail2ban.filter         [9162]: INFO      findtime: 60
2023-10-16 15:03:08,750 fail2ban.actions        [9162]: INFO      banTime: 300
2023-10-16 15:03:08,750 fail2ban.CommandAction  [9162]: DEBUG   Created <class 'fail2ban.server.action.CommandAction'>
2023-10-16 15:03:08,750 fail2ban.CommandAction  [9162]: DEBUG     Set actionunban = '/opt/scripts/ban.sh Unban <ip>'
2023-10-16 15:03:08,750 fail2ban.CommandAction  [9162]: DEBUG     Set actionstop = 'rm -f /var/log/fail2ban_debug.log'
2023-10-16 15:03:08,750 fail2ban.CommandAction  [9162]: DEBUG     Set actionban = '/opt/scripts/ban.sh Ban <ip>'
2023-10-16 15:03:08,750 fail2ban.CommandAction  [9162]: DEBUG     Set actionstart = 'touch /var/log/fail2ban_debug.log'
2023-10-16 15:03:08,751 fail2ban.CommandAction  [9162]: DEBUG     Set actname = 'my-action'
2023-10-16 15:03:08,751 fail2ban.CommandAction  [9162]: DEBUG     Set name = 'my-jail'
2023-10-16 15:03:08,751 fail2ban.jail           [9162]: DEBUG   Starting jail 'my-jail'
2023-10-16 15:03:08,753 fail2ban.jail           [9162]: INFO    Jail 'my-jail' started
2023-10-16 15:03:08,754 fail2ban.transmitter    [9162]: DEBUG   Status: ready
2023-10-16 15:03:08,756 fail2ban.utils          [9162]: DEBUG   7f36b00f7490 -- returned successfully 0
```

```
[root@ip-172-31-89-74 action.d]# systemctl status fail2ban
● fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-10-16 15:03:08 CEST; 35min ago
     Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
  Process: 8983 ExecStop=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9160 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/fail2ban (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9162 (fail2ban-server)
   CGroup: /system.slice/fail2ban.service
           └─9162 /usr/bin/python2 -s /usr/bin/fail2ban-server -xf start

Oct 16 15:03:08 ip-172-31-89-74.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting Fail2Ban Service...
Oct 16 15:03:08 ip-172-31-89-74.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started Fail2Ban Service.
Oct 16 15:03:08 ip-172-31-89-74.eu-central-1.compute.internal fail2ban-server[9162]: Server ready
```

#### Testing in bash from a specific IP address

```
i=0;while true; do echo -e"\n---------------------------------$i-----------------------------\n"; curl -s -L testing.my-org.de/tests
; i=$(($i+1));
```

This generates lines in the expected log in the jail.local

I confirm that the actionstart works, as there is a logfile. Also I get e-mails whenever I restart the service.
What am I missing, or doing incorrectly?

#### More data:

```
222.222.222.222 - - [16/Oct/2023:22:10:51 +0200] "testing.my-org.com" "GET /tests HTTP/1.1" 404 8043 61680 "-" "curl/7.88.1" "" "ea4uh580h9dl7tat34q2d5cjo7" 
222.222.222.222 - - [16/Oct/2023:22:10:52 +0200] "testing.my-org.com" "GET /tests HTTP/1.1" 404 8043 61976 "-" "curl/7.88.1" "" "uou7bo5pj4tgp2m9t5kulkmvn2" 
222.222.222.222 - - [16/Oct/2023:22:10:52 +0200] "testing.my-org.com" "GET /tests HTTP/1.1" 404 8043 68577 "-" "curl/7.88.1" "" "m3u0g2s41fa6igphsfecrdbg41"


[root@ip-172-31-89-74 apache2]# fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/frontend-app-my-org-com-access.log.1 /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/my-filter.conf

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : my-filter, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : /var/log/apache2/frontend-app-my-org-com-access.log.1
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 2480 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [2480] ^<HOST>
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [2480] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])MON(?P=_sep)ExYear[ :]?24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Zone offset)?
`-

Lines: 2480 lines, 0 ignored, 2480 matched, 0 missed
[processed in 0.17 sec]

[root@ip-172-31-89-74 apache2]# vim /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/my-filter.conf
[root@ip-172-31-89-74 apache2]# fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/frontend-app-my-org-com-access.log.1 /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/my-filter.conf

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : my-filter, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : /var/log/apache2/frontend-app-my-org-com-access.log.1
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 2480 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [2480] ^<HOST> - - \[.*\] \".*.my-org.*\" \".*\" [4-5][0-9][0-9]
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [2480] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])MON(?P=_sep)ExYear[ :]?24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Zone offset)?
`-

Lines: 2480 lines, 0 ignored, 2480 matched, 0 missed
[processed in 0.18 sec]
```

Comment: You've got `maxretry = 4` and `findtime = 60`, so you need four problematic log lines in a 60 second period to trigger a ban. Are you getting those entries in the defined time interval? You should see corresponding `Found` lines in your `/var/log/fail2ban.log` or equivalent (defined as `logtarget` in `/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf`)

Comment: with the last line (while loop) I generate over 50 lines in 60 seconds, so I expect that this should work.

`logtarget = /var/log/fail2ban.log`

I don't see any `Found` there

Comment: Also posted at https://superuser.com/q/1812901/332907

Answer (score 1):

As already answered in https://superuser.com/a/1813168/1131979:

1. `fail2ban-regex` does test filter/failregex only. Nothing else.
2. `Jail 'my-jail' uses systemd` means that fail2ban would monitor systemd journal (probably your default backend), not the log file `/var/log/...-access.log`. If you want monitor `logpath` instead, you need to switch to some file-related backend, like `pyinotify` or `polling` or simply specify `backend = auto` for the jail.

Also note that your regex is a bit vulnerable due to several catch-alls.

And last but not least - note [fail2ban :: wiki :: Best practice (reduce parasitic log-traffic)](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/Best-practice#reduce-parasitic-log-traffic).

Comment: Thank you, I've added a line in the jail.local that states backend = auto and now I see the "Found" messages in the fail2ban.log file.
I'll also modify the regex.